# why does this UIAlertController fail to find nil while unwrapping an Optional value?

Tags: ios, swift, uiview, uiviewcontroller, subclass

I’m trying to “*be a good citizen*” by keeping `View` code separate from the `ViewController` ([see this](https://swiftandpainless.com/dont-put-view-code-into-your-view-controller/)) and I’m wondering if this could also apply to code for a `UIAlertController.`

However the Apple documentation [says](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uialertcontroller?changes=latest_minor):

> The UIAlertController class is intended to be used as-is and does not support subclassing. The view hierarchy for this class is private and must not be modified.

Despite this I thought it might still be possible to subclass a `UIAlertController` - yes, I realise that `UIAlertController` is not a `View` - so I tried the simple test example *below*.

The code includes subclassed views with layout constraints. A `UIButton` is used to activate the alert (and eventually the target action will become the basis of a function that could be called from another class).

The code runs but as soon as the button is pressed Xcode goes into debug at the following line

```
    self.view.present(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

with the message

```
    fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value
    (lldb)
```

Have I made a mistake ? or am I trying to do something impossible ?

**ViewController.swift**

```
    import UIKit

    class ViewController: UIViewController {

    var launch: TestView {
    return view as! TestView
    }

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
    }

    override func loadView() {
        let contentView                     = TestView(frame: .zero)
        view                                = contentView
    }
}
```

**TestView.swift**

```
import UIKit

class TestView: UIView {

    var view:ViewController!

    override init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: frame)
        view.self   = view
        
        addBehavior()
    }
    
    convenience init() {
        self.init(frame: CGRect.zero)

    }
    
    required init(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("This class does not support NSCoding")
    }
    
    func addBehavior() {
        
        let spacer: UIView                = UIView (frame: .zero)
        spacer.backgroundColor            = UIColor.white
        
        let view: UIView                = UIView (frame: .zero)
        view.backgroundColor            = UIColor.lightGray
        view.alpha                      = 0.5
        
        let button: UIButton            = UIButton(frame: .zero)
        button.backgroundColor          = UIColor.blue
        button.setTitleColor(UIColor.white, for: UIControlState.normal)
        button.setTitle("test", for: .normal)
        button.addTarget(self, action: #selector(showExcessNotesAlert), for: .touchUpInside)
        
        let stackView                   = UIStackView(arrangedSubviews: [spacer, view, button])
        stackView.axis                  = .vertical
        stackView.spacing               = 5
        stackView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false

        addSubview(stackView)
        
        let views                       = ["stackView": stackView]
        
        var layoutConstraints           = [NSLayoutConstraint]()
        layoutConstraints += NSLayoutConstraint.constraints(withVisualFormat: "|-[stackView]-|", options: [], metrics: nil, views: views)
        layoutConstraints.append(spacer.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 30))
        layoutConstraints.append(view.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 450))
        layoutConstraints.append(button.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 50))
        NSLayoutConstraint.activate(layoutConstraints)
        
        backgroundColor                 = .white
    }

    func showExcessNotesAlert(_ sender: UIButton) {
        
        let alert           = UIAlertController(title: "Alert", message: "Grow a brain", preferredStyle: .alert)
        let defaultAction   = UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: .default, handler: nil)
        alert.addAction(defaultAction)
        self.view.present(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }
}
```

Comment: Do you know the difference between UIView and UIViewController?

Comment: @El Tomato, in principle, I think so, but what I’d like know is why it is possible to subclass UIViews that appear in a UIViewController and whether it is possible to achieve something similar with UIAlertController

Answer (score 2):

There are several problems in here, but the likely cause of your crash is this line:

```
view.self   = view
```

That's not valid code for several reasons, but the reason it's crashing is that you're trying to access a variable (`view`), which you have defined as an implicitly unwrapped optional (by putting the "!" at the end), yet you never initialize it before trying to access, so of course it's nil.  The bare minimum initialization would be to replace `view.self = view` with `self.view = UIViewController()`.  I don't fully understand what you want to do with that `view` variable, but making my suggested change will likely cause that crash to stop.

Ultimately, I don't see any code in your snippet to suggest you shouldn't just use the built-in UIAlertController from within your viewController.  Again, it's a little hard to follow exactly what you're hoping to achieve.

Comment: the crash stops with your initialisation. report changes to Warning: Attempt to present <UIAlertController:> on <UIViewController:> whose view is not in the window hierarchy!

Comment: @Greg Yes, as I mentioned there are other problems with your code, and you may just want to do the alertController instead.